# Cleanest way to create a mock/stub a FilterUserResponseEvent instance?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am writing a php website using Symfony.

I am writing a module that listens for a `FilterUserResponseEvent` object.

I would like to create a mock `FilterUserResponseEvent` object that will contain a suitable request object that contains a cookie that I can set.

i.e. I would like to manufacture a suitable `$event` variable to pass into the function below. I would like to be able to pre-define the result of `$value = $request->cookies->get('cookie');` inside my test.

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;

public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{

    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $request  = $event->getRequest();

    // get cookie
    $value = $request->cookies->get('cookie');

}
```

How could I do that? I am trying the following code

```
   $request = new stdClass();      
   $request->cookies = new stdClass();
   $request->cookies->get = function($key){
       return 'cookie';
   };

   print(  $request->cookies->get('asd'));
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::get()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to just use the `Request` and `Cookie` class from Http-Foundation component.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$request = new Request();
$request->cookies = new ParameterBag($your_cookies);
```

`Request` class does not need any specific arg from environment to work properly. Also as you can see in [Tests](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/tree/master/Tests) for Http-Foundation, no stub is used.

Comment: Thanks. You've reminded me that sometimes the best way to learn about something is to just look at the source code!